# Is this conditional to hide scrollbar doing the same thing as overflow: auto?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-typescript

I'm refactoring some code and am just wondering whether this:

```
export const ScrollableWindow = styled.div(({hideScrollBar}: {hideScrollBar?: boolean}) => ({
  position: 'absolute',
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  overflowY: hideScrollBar ? 'hidden': 'scroll',
}))
```

and this:

```
export const ScrollableWindow = styled.div(() => ({
  position: 'absolute',
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  overflow: 'auto'
}))
```

are doing the same thing?

Comment: In the second code segment, you are letting CSS handle whether scrollbar should be displayed or not based on content. In the first segment, you are controlling whether the scrollbar should be displayed or not.

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: auto;` checks if the content inside is overflowed horizontally or vertically, if it's the case then you'll see scrollbars in either direction.

In contrast, in the first code block you're manually deciding the overflowing style for the component.

To conclude, i'd say no, but if you can, just leave it to the system to take care of the overflowing style.